# Single Step KDF specification

Tags: library, java, security

NIST SP 56A talks about Single Step Key derivation function. Is there any Java library which implements this?

Comment: What license should the library have? GPL? LGPL? Redistributable? What is your budget?

Comment: GPL or LGPL would do.